# C++ Qt QPixmap load always returns false

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

I try to load an image using QPixmap.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPixmap test;
    qDebug()<< test.load(":/test.bmp");
}
```

No matter how I change the file path, it always returns false. What's wrong?

Comment: print `QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()`

Comment: And make sure that the file have been properly added to your resources.

Comment: Do you have a qresource?

Comment: I think there is no problem in the file path because the picture will show when the mouse moves on it.

Comment: @regetyu 
if the image is shown it is because Qt can read it, and there we go again, provide a [mcve], have you printed what I told you?

Comment: ("bmp", "cur", "gif", "icns", "ico", "jpeg", "jpg", "pbm", "pgm", "png", "ppm", "svg", "svgz", "tga", "tif", "tiff", "wbmp", "webp", "xbm", "xpm")

Comment: @regetyu
Then the problem is another, you could share your project via github, drive or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Add following line to your .pro file.

```
RESOURCES += test.bmp
```

File paths that start with a colon like the ":/test.bmp" above are treated like resources (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) and are compiled into the binary, so you don't need to ship them as files (I would only use a resource if the BMP file is not that big, because it will be in memory when the binary is loaded).

Alternatively, you could just give the relative or absolute path to your file in `QPixmap::load()` without the colon, e.g. `test.load("test.bmp")`.